# Safely use CryptSignAndEncryptMessage?

Tags: encryption, rsa, signature, authenticated-encryption

I am developing an application that sends messages which I want to encrypt and sign. The CryptoApi offers a function called [CryptSignAndEncryptMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380278%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
The description says, what this function actually does:

> The **CryptSignAndEncryptMessage** function creates a hash of the
>   specified content, signs the hash, encrypts the content, hashes the
>   encrypted contents and the signed hash, and then encodes both the
>   encrypted content and the signed hash. The result is the same as if
>   the hash were first signed and then encrypted.

If I understood correctly, this solution could be susceptible to an attack called [surreptitious forwarding](http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html)?

Surreptitious forwarding uses the naive "sign and encrypt" approach to allow B to forward a message of A, destined to B, to a third party C and make C think the message was from B, destined to C (although it was from A to B, and just forwarded by B). This is possible because B can decrypt the signed message and re-encrypt it for C. 
However, although a message can be forwarded "illegally", the actual message content cannot be changed.

Does this in turn mean, if I include the receiver in the signed data, I am not susceptible to this attack?

Comment: Don't you want to say "make C think the message was from A, destined to C"? I think there is no way to avoid the case described in your question, as "from B, destined to C" can just be faked by B signing and encrypting it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I understood correctly, this solution could be susceptible to an attack called surreptitious forwarding?

If CryptSignAndEncryptMessage is implemented in the naive way, then it would seem that it is vulnerable to a forwarding attack. Microsoft has not published the exact details (AFAIK), so it is difficult to tell for sure.

> Does this in turn mean, if I include the receiver in the signed data, I am not susceptible to this attack?

There is a published recommendation done by a few very respectable cryptographers. It is in Section 7 of [On the Security of Joint Signature and Encryption](http://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2002/23320080/adr.pdf#page=18), and is along similar lines to what you propose. Specifically, they recommend:

> 1. Whenever encrypting something, include the identity of the sender $ID_S$ together
>      with the encrypted message.
> 2. Whenever signing something, include the identity of the receiver $ID_R$ together with
>      the signed message.
> 3. On the receiving side, whenever either the identity of the sender or of the receiver
>      do not match what is expected, output $\bot$.